# probability of hand with at least 2 kings

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A hand $H$ of 5 cards is chosen randomly from a standard deck of 52. Let $E_1$ be the event that H has at least one King and let $E_2$ be the event that $H$ has at least 2 Kings. What is the conditional probability $\mathbb P(E_2|E_1)$?

Solution:
$$\mathbb P(E_2|E_1)=1-\frac{4\binom{48}4}{\binom{52}5-\binom{48}5}.$$
Would this be a correct solution (obtained by looking at a similar problem)? I'm a bit confused by this solution, can someone walk me through it so I can understand.

Comment: Maybe you should start by calculating the probability that a hand has at least one king, and the probability that a hand has at least two kings. Can you do those?

Comment: i can calculate the prob. that a hand has at least one king:  $$1- \frac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$ but don't know how to calculate the prob. that a hand has 2 kings

Comment: Suppose that a hand has exactly one king. There are $4$ choices for the king and $\binom{48}4$ choices for the other $4$ cards, so there are $4\binom{48}4$ hands with exactly one king. You also know how many have no kings. Now can you calculate the number with at least two kings?

Answer (score 2):

We have by the definition of conditional probability
$$\Pr(E_2|E_1)=\frac{\Pr(E_1\cap E_2)}{\Pr(E_1)}.$$
We calculate the two probabilities on the right-hand side.

The probability of $E_1$ is $1$ minus the probability of no Kings. You calculated $\Pr(E_1)$ correctly.

For the probability of $E_1\cap E_2$, which is just the probability of $E_2$, use the same basic strategy. The number of $1$ King hands is $\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{4}$, for we have to choose $4$ non-Kings to go with the King. So the probability of at least $2$ Kings is
$$1-\frac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{48}{5}+\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{52}{5}}.$$

Comment: so the my attempted answer would then be the simplified version of your solution since (4 choose 0) will simplify to 1 and (4 choose 1) will simplify to 4 and we subtract (48 choose 5) from the numerator and therefore from the denominator as well

Comment: I had noticed that your $\Pr(E_1)$ was right, but hadn't noticed that the ultimate result was also right. The $\binom{4}{0}$ was of course purely decorative. The point is that the "tops" add up to $52$ and the bottoms to $5$, which makes things look more structured.