# What is the probability of of drawing at least one king and one ace in a five card poker hand?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

The title problem is just one specific example of a more generalized problem that I'm trying to solve.  I'm trying to write an efficient algorithm for calculating the probability of at least k occurrences each of several dependent events occurring in a particular sample space.  It is the presence of wildcards and multiple types of events here that is making the problem difficult for me.

I found this post partially helpful in guiding me:
[probability of hand with at least 2 kings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327072/probability-of-hand-with-at-least-2-kings)

I can't figure out how to modify it to accommodate for different card types.  I tried subtracting from 1 the sum of the probabilities of drawing a hand containing each proper subset of the minimal set of cards and adding those together.  Note that 44 is the number of non-Kings and non-Aces in the deck:

1 -

[

Pr(0K and 0A) : <sub>4</sub>C<sub>0</sub> * <sub>4</sub>C<sub>0</sub> * <sub>44</sub>C<sub>5</sub> +

Pr(1K and 0A) : <sub>4</sub>C<sub>1</sub> * <sub>4</sub>C<sub>0</sub> * <sub>44</sub>C<sub>4</sub> +

Pr(0K and 1A) : <sub>4</sub>C<sub>0</sub> * <sub>4</sub>C<sub>1</sub> * <sub>44</sub>C<sub>4</sub>

]

But this of course omits the possibility of getting 2-4 Kings (if and only if none of the other cards is an Ace) and getting 2-4 Aces (if and only if none of the other cards is a King).  I need a little push in the right direction to help me develop a generalized solution to this problem.

BTW, I'm looking for a method that is more efficient than enumerating all valid combinations, and summing their probabilities.  Assume that the method should work somewhat efficiently such that instead of a five card poker hand, it's a billion card poker hand drawn from millions of decks shuffled together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ${48 \choose 5}/{52 \choose 5}$ is probability of no Aces
- ${48 \choose 5}/{52 \choose 5}$ is probability of no Kings
- ${44 \choose 5}/{52 \choose 5}$ is probability of no Aces or Kings

so by [inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the probability of at least one Ace and at least one King is

$$\dfrac{ \displaystyle{52 \choose 5} - 2{48 \choose 5} + {44 \choose 5}}{ \displaystyle{52 \choose 5} }$$

which is close to $10\%$.

Comment: I think I might have over-simplified my example problem, since I'm still having a bit of difficulty.  The given response does correctly answer the original question, but perhaps I should have asked a more complicated question like "The probability of getting at least 1 Queen, 2 Kings and 3 Aces in a 7 card hand."  This might help demonstrate how to correctly apply the inclusion-exclusion principle.  I can accept your answer and start a new question if that would be more appropriate.

Comment: I posted a new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543400/what-is-the-probability-of-of-drawing-at-least-1-queen-2-kings-and-3-aces-in-a.  Thanks for your help Henry.