# What is the probability of of drawing at least 1 C, 2 Ds and 3 As in a 7 tile draw from a standard/full Scrabble bag?

Tags: combinatorics

The title problem is just one specific example of a more generalized problem that I'm trying to solve. I'm trying to write an efficient algorithm for calculating the probability of at least k occurrences each of several dependent events occurring in a particular sample space. It is the presence of wildcards and multiple types of events here that is making the problem difficult for me.

I asked a similar version of the problem here: [What is the probability of of drawing at least 1 queen, 2 kings and 3 aces in a 9 card draw of a standard 52 card deck?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543400/what-is-the-probability-of-of-drawing-at-least-1-queen-2-kings-and-3-aces-in-a)
I'm rephrasing the question hopefully to employ the help of some avid Scrabble players who have encountered this type of problem.

I'm trying to employ [inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) here.  I think seeing the answer to the title problem (without any reductions) will help me design my algorithm for the general case.  This is what I have so far:

$R := $ the set of all 7-tile racks

$$|R| = {\binom{100}{7}}.$$

$C := $ the set of all 7-tile racks containing zero Cs (there are 2 Cs in the bag):
$$|C| = {\binom{2}{0}\binom{98}{7}}.$$

$C_a := $ the set of all 7-tile racks containing at least one C:
$$|C_a| = {|R|-|C|}$$

$D := $ the set of all 7-tile racks containing zero or one D (there are 4 Ds in the bag):
$$|D| = {\binom{4}{0}\binom{96}{7}+\binom{4}{1}\binom{96}{6}}$$

$D_a := $ the set of all 7-tile racks containing at least two Ds:
$$|D_a| = {|R|-|D|}$$

$A := $ the set of all 7-tile racks containing zero, one or two As (there are 9 As in the bag):
$$|A| = {\binom{9}{0}\binom{91}{7}+\binom{9}{1}\binom{91}{6}+\binom{9}{2}\binom{91}{5}}$$

$A_a := $ the set of all 7-tile racks containing at least three As:
$$|A_a| = {|R|-|A|}$$

$X := $ the set of all 7-tile racks containing at least 1 C, 2 Ds and 3 As:
$$|X| = |R|-[|C|+|D|+|A|-|C\cap D|-|D\cap A|-|C\cap A|+|C\cap D\cap A|]$$

And of course, the probability of drawing one such rack is just:
$$\frac{|X|}{|R|}$$

Is that correct so far?  This is where I feel it's getting complicated.  How do you calculate for example $|D\cap A|$?  What does it mean to be a rack with "(zero or one D) AND (zero, one or two As)"?  This smells like we would need to find all valid sets of $d$ Ds and $a$ As and add their cardinalities together.

$S(d,a) := $ the set of 7-tile racks containing exactly $d$ Ds and $a$ As

$S(c,d,a) := $ the set of 7-tile racks containing exactly $c$ Cs, $d$ Ds and $a$ As

First, are the following correct?

$$|S(d,a)| = \binom{4}{d}\binom{9}{a}\binom{87}{7-d-a}$$
$$|S(c,d,a)| = \binom{2}{c}\binom{4}{d}\binom{9}{a}\binom{85}{7-c-d-a}$$

If so, are the following true?

$$|D\cap A| = \sum\limits_{a=0}^{2}\sum\limits_{d=0}^{1} |S(d,a)|$$
$$|C\cap D\cap A| = \sum\limits_{a=0}^{2}\sum\limits_{d=0}^{1}\sum\limits_{c=0}^{0} |S(c,d,a)|$$

Is there a simplification that perhaps I'm missing?  I feel like I've over-complicated this problem (or at least I hope I have).

Any help is appreciated.  Feel free to reference in your response any sets or functions defined here.  Also, can someone tag this post with "scrabble"?  My rep isn't high enough to create a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution indicates that you need atleast 1C in a 7 tile rack and should include atleast 2D in the 7-tile rack and similarly atleast 3As in the 7 tile rack.

This should lead to the possible combinations to maintain the condition.

1) 1C,2D,3A,Anything other than these Totals a 7 tile rack

2) 2C,2D,3A Totals a 7 tile rack

3) 1C,3D,3A Totals a 7 tile rack

4) 1C,2D,4A Totals a 7 tile rack

we note that the probability of a given draw is given by

(Product (fi Choose ai))/100C7

Where fi is the number of tiles of the same letter and ai is the number of that letter that 
you want to draw

Required Probability  = (2C1*4C2*9C3*85C1 + 2C2*4C2*9C3 + 2C1*4C3*9C3 + 2C1*4C2*9C4)/100C7

Thanks

Satish