# Conditional probability: At least 3 kings given there are at least 2 kings in the hand of 13.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

My first "conditional probability" problem. Sorry for all the questions. My instructor doesn't make sense to the class.

A hand of 13 cards is to be dealt at random and without any replacement from an ordinary deck of playing cards. 
**Find the conditional probability that there are at least three kings in the hand given that the hand contains at least two kings.**

A deep, good, and thorough explanation would be tremendously appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Strongly related: [probability of hand with at least 2 kings](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327072/probability-of-hand-with-at-least-2-kings?rq=1)

Comment: I am probably not fast enough to type a detailed answer before the question is closed as a duplicate. It isn't, since the problem is different and OP in that case had made substantial progress, so needed minimal explanation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas The only difference is $P(X\ge 3 | X\ge 2)$ instead of $P(X\ge 2|X\ge 1)$ and the number of cards dealt. This means a careful reading of the question is likely to either solve the problem or concreticise the question; in wich case it may be edited to reopen.

Comment: @hardmath I was aware of this, but since the close vote pointed to a different link than intended, I decided to point it out so other voters could see that I selected the wrong question as duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are $\binom{52}{13}$ ways to select 13 cards from 52 cards.
Consider how you would create a hand of 13 cards with the required number of kings.
There are $\binom{4}{n}$ ways of choosing the required number of kings.
There are then $\binom{48}{13-n}$ ways of choosing the remaining (13 - n) cards.

Let A be the event of getting at least 2 kings.
This can be thought of as 3 separate events corresponding to 2, 3 or 4 kings.
By the addition principle:

Number of ways of getting A = $\binom{4}{2}$ * $\binom{48}{13-2}$ + $\binom{4}{3}$ * $\binom{48}{13-3}$  + $\binom{4}{4}$ * $\binom{48}{13-4}$

So, $$P(A) = \frac{\binom{4}{2} * \binom{48}{13-2} + \binom{4}{3} * \binom{48}{13-3}  + \binom{4}{4} * \binom{48}{13-4}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

Let B be the event of getting at least 3 kings.
This can be thought of as 2 separate events corresponding to 3 or 4 kings.
By the addition principle:
$$P(B) = \frac{\binom{4}{3} * \binom{48}{13-3}  + \binom{4}{4} * \binom{48}{13-4}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

Finally, by the conditional probability formula:

$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}= \frac{P(B)}{P(A)}$$

Answer (score 0):

My Probability is not so good but still here's a solution.

Let $\Pr(A)$ is the probability of having at least two King cards in a hand of 13 cards.

Hence, $\Pr(A) = \binom{4}{2} * \binom{48}{11} + \binom{4}{3}*\binom{48}{10}+\binom{4}{4}*\binom{48}{9}$

And let $\Pr(B)$ is the probability of having at least three King cards in a hand of 13 cards.

And let $\Pr(C)$ is the probability of "having at least 2 king cards and having at least 3 kings cards" simultaneously. This is indeed the case you have at least 3 king cards in one hand of 13 cards.

Basically, $\Pr(C)=\Pr(A \cap B)$

Hence, $ \Pr( C )= \binom{4}{4}*\binom{48}{9}+ \binom{4}{3}*\binom{48}{10}$

So, required probability is $\Pr (B|A)= \large\frac{\Pr(C)}{\Pr(A)}$

I have used the conditional probability formula.

Comment: This may seem dumb, but can you explain the different numbers in the Pr(A) and Pr(C)? I'm trying to get a good grasp on it so I can try to work other problems on my own. @user3679857

Comment: $\Pr(A)$ is actually sum of probabilities of exactly 2 kings, exactly 3 kings and exactly 4 kings. Similarly, $\Pr(C)$ is sum of probabilities of exactly 3 kings and exactly 4 kings.

Comment: @user3679857 Your Pr(A) and Pr(B) are not probabilities. They are the number of ways of getting the required hands. You need to divide the numbers by $\binom{52}{13}$. Your final probability is right though because the $\binom{52}{13}$ cancels out.